# spyOn TS error when passing array iteration instead of string

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Instead of having repeating test cases and only changing a couple of values I've created an Array and just looping over them.

The problem with that is I'm getting TS error in `test` when it's passed from Array instead of string `testLink`

Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(object: { registerLink: () => void; }, method: "registerLink"): SpyInstance<void, []>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"registerLink"'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(object: { registerLink: () => void; }, method: never): SpyInstance<never, never>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2769)
```

Component.test.tsx

```
  for (let i = 0; i < testProp.length; i++) {
    it(`test default props of ${testProp[i].name}`, () => {
      const test = testProp[i].name
      jest.spyOn(ComponentDefaultProp, test)
    })
  }
```

But when i pass it as a string, no errors

```
  for (let i = 0; i < testProp.length; i++) {
    it(`test default props of ${testProp[i].name}`, () => {
      jest.spyOn(ComponentDefaultProp, 'testLink')
    })
  }
```

The array that I'm looping over

```
const testProp = [
  {
    name: 'testLink',
  },
]
```

What I have tried that worked but I would like NOT to use `any`

Test 1

```
  for (let i = 0; i < testProp.length; i++) {
    it(`test default props of ${testProp[i].name}`, () => {
      const test: any = testProp[i].name
      jest.spyOn(ComponentDefaultProp, test)
    })
  }
```

Test 2

```
  for (let i = 0; i < testProp.length; i++) {
    it(`test default props of ${testProp[i].name}`, () => {
      const test = testProp[i].name
      jest.spyOn<any, string>(ComponentDefaultProp, test)
    })
  }
```

Screenshot from spyOn
[image]

The end goal is to use an array but not get TS error and avoid using `any` if possible

Answer (score 1):

Add correct types for `testProp` variable. Below example using `"typescript": "^3.6.4"`.

E.g.

`index.test.ts`:

```js
const ComponentDefaultProp = {
  testLink() {
    return 'real testLink implementation';
  },
  testAnother() {
    return 'real testAnother implementation';
  },
};

describe('63615134', () => {
  const testProp: Array<{ name: keyof typeof ComponentDefaultProp }> = [{ name: 'testLink' }, { name: 'testAnother' }];

  for (let i = 0; i < testProp.length; i++) {
    it(`test default props of ${testProp[i].name}`, () => {
      const test = testProp[i].name;
      jest.spyOn(ComponentDefaultProp, test);
      ComponentDefaultProp[test]();
      expect(ComponentDefaultProp[test]).toBeCalled();
    });
  }
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63615134/index.test.ts (10.697s)
  63615134
    ✓ test default props of testLink (5ms)
    ✓ test default props of testAnother (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.982s
```